# Jquery SimpleModal: what is the purpose of the container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I am trying to use the jQuery [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin and I am curious about something: The description page mentions a "container" div. What is the purpose of this? Do I need to use it to use the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

The container is the div that holds the contents you want to appear in the modal window. It's not something you create but rather what the plugin creates. So, yes you need it, but it's not something you need to explicitly create yourself.